# Day/Hour Grouped Array from single date using Lodash and Moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, lodash

I'm trying to transform my array so that its easily used while rendering views

I have this sample code for now

```
let arr = [
    {
        date: d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1),
        name: "john",
        country: "AU",
        text: "Hey"
    },
    {
        date: d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1),
        name: "jake",
        country: "US",
        text: "Hey"
    },
    {
        date:d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3),
        name: "jeff",
        country: "US",
        text: "Hey"
    },
    {
        date:d.setDate(d.getDate() - 5),
        name: "jared",
        country: "US",
        text: "Hey"
    },
    {
        date:d.setDate(d.getDate() - 2),
        name: "jane",
        country: "UK",
        text: "Hey"
    }
]

let hours = _.groupBy(arr, (result) => moment(result['date']).startOf('hour').format("LT"));
let day = _.groupBy(arr, (result) => moment(result['date']).startOf('day').format("MMM Do YY"));


console.log(day)
```

What i want is to group the data by hours which is grouped by days from a single "date" string (i can do that seperately via _.groupby function but i want it to output a combined array.

The desired output should be something like this :

```
{
    'Apr 15th 19': [
        {'4 pm':[
            {
                date: 1555318593445,
                name: 'ahmed',
                country: 'AU',
                text: 'Hey'
            }
        ]
    ]
}....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.flow()` to create a function that groups by the day, and then maps each days values, and groups them by the hour:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, mapValues } = _

const fn = flow(
  arr => groupBy(arr, v => moment(v.date).startOf('day').format("MMM Do YY")),
  groups => mapValues(groups, g => _.groupBy(g, v =>
    moment(v.date).startOf('hour').format("LT")
  ))
)

const arr = [{"date":1555318593445,"name":"john","country":"AU","text":"Hey"},{"date":155531859300,"name":"jake","country":"US","text":"Hey"},{"date":1555316593445,"name":"jeff","country":"US","text":"Hey"},{"date":1555316593345,"name":"jared","country":"US","text":"Hey"},{"date":155531659400,"name":"jane","country":"UK","text":"Hey"}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the terser lodash/fp version:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, mapValues } = _

const fn = flow(
  groupBy(v => moment(v.date).startOf('day').format("MMM Do YY")),
  mapValues(_.groupBy(v => moment(v.date).startOf('hour').format("LT")))
)

const arr = [{"date":1555318593445,"name":"john","country":"AU","text":"Hey"},{"date":155531859300,"name":"jake","country":"US","text":"Hey"},{"date":1555316593445,"name":"jeff","country":"US","text":"Hey"},{"date":1555316593345,"name":"jared","country":"US","text":"Hey"},{"date":155531659400,"name":"jane","country":"UK","text":"Hey"}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comments Q&A:

### How is flow different from chain?

Flow generates a function that runs the code in a sequence and passes the results of one function call to the next one. The lodash chain runs the code, but tries to make lazy evaluation, and combines several calls to a single one, which means that a chain of .map.filter will only iterate the array once.

However, the laziness comes with a price, you need to import the entire lodash module for it to work. While using flow, you can import just the functions that you need.

### why mapvalues was the second step?

The result of the 1st group is an object { date: {}, date: {} ), and you need to group each the object values by itself. To do so you need to map the values of each date, and group them by the hour.

Comment: for my own understanding could you explain a few things such as : how is flow different from chain? why mapvalues was the second step? i tried using 2 groupBy in a chain function but couldnt get that outcome... just trying to wrap my head around this to solve any issues myself later any explanation is appreciated!

Comment: one more question, how would i go about sorting the entire array (outer=date and inner = time) by date/time etc (newest date fierst and inside it the last time first)?

Comment: Sort the original array by datetime, and then group the items. The original sort order would be preserved.